# __attribute__((pure)) applied to void function

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, attributes, compiler-optimization

I have a function that takes two arrays and writes into a third array the result of a `pure` function (c_i = a_i / b_i):

```
inline
void    array_division      (ptrdiff_t nmemb,
                             double dest[static nmemb],
                             const double src1[static nmemb],
                             const double src2[static nmemb])
        __attribute__((nonnull, pure));

inline
void    array_division      (ptrdiff_t nmemb,
                             double dest[static nmemb],
                             const double src1[static nmemb],
                             const double src2[static nmemb])
{

        for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < nmemb; i++)
                dest[i] = src1[i] / src2[i];
}
```

GCC throws an error, because it doesn't expect a pure function to return `void`.

A [pure function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) is one that acts as a function of its parameters, and the values pointed to by those parameters; and if none of the parameters, nor the values pointed to by them, change between two calls, they should be redundant and the call can be omitted, evaluating to the same value returned by the previous call.

My function follows all those rules:  If none of the 3 arrays change between two function calls, the function call can be completely removed; and they evaluate to the same value (which is none, because it's `void`).

Am I right in thinking that GCC should allow this usage of `__attibute__((pure))`?

Should I return a dummy `return 0;` to avoid GCC complaining?

**EDIT:**

BUG status in GCC: [__ attribute __((pure)) to function with non-const pointers](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91107)

Comment: A pure function also doesn't change anything (which is the very reason why the call can be omitted), so i'd be surprised if non-const pointers were allowed.

Comment: @cHao True, as per the literal text of the documentation, but based on the principles of `pure` I think this function should be able to be optimized exactly as any other `pure` function.  Maybe the text should be revised.

Comment: @cHao BTW, GCC 8.3 doesn't complain if I add the dummy `return 0;`.  I don't know if it's silently disabling the optimization or if I successfully tricked GCC, though.  I think I tricked it.

Comment: Personally, I'd consider that a compiler bug. It defeats the entire purpose of pure functions.

Comment: I'd say that returning the second argument (as a pointer) makes more sense than returning 0, and is arguably more useful than returning `void` since it allows chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not follow the rules of a pure function. The linked-to text very clearly, **multiple times** says that changing the observable state of the program is not allowed through the pointers passed into a function. The only thing observable from a pure function is its return value. **Modifying memory through a non-const pointer is not returning a value, but a side effect.**

Your function is not pure because it has side effects. If the return value of a pure function is deemed unused by the optimizer, it åneed not be **called at all**, not even the first time.

Hence a void function is not useful as pure, as it is a function that **must be** optimizable to `void nop() { }`. It does not make any sense.

The only compiler and documentation  error here is that the compiler suppressed diagnostics when you added the doubly-wrong return 0.

---

You have discovered another set of functions that could have an optimization attribute - idempotent. However the problem there is that one can only elide repeated calls - but unlike using `strlen` in a loop condition, there is hardly any reason to do repeated calls to an idempotent function with the same arguments.

Comment: Then a new attribute may be created; possibly named *idempotent*; a bit looser than pure, but with similar implications

Comment: @cacachuete That might be useful yes.

Answer (score 4):

As for why `return 0;` works...
According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-pure-function-attribute :

> Because a pure function cannot have any observable side effects it does not make sense for such a function to return `void`. Declaring such a function is diagnosed.

But note also the very reason you can't return `void`: it *doesn't make sense*. You'd be giving up the ability of returning a value, and with it the only legitimate purpose of a pure function.

> The `pure` attribute prohibits a function from modifying the state of the program that is observable by means other than inspecting the function’s return value.

That means, for example, that a function marked with `pure` is prohibited from setting entries in that array you passed in. I'm a bit surprised it allows non-const pointers at all, much less assignment through them.

As for what happens once you've tricked GCC into allowing modifications in such a function, i'm not sure. It depends on what GCC has specified it will do in that case.

Comment: OP's point, more or less, is that the restriction specified in the GCC manual requires the function to be *idempotent*, which is a looser requirement than *pure*. An idempotent function can store a value into a non-volatile object as long as the value being stored is the same as the value previous to the mutation. In theory, that should allow a function to be pure even if it returns its value into an "out" parameter passed by reference, as with Peanut's example. Whether that is actually the intention of the pure attribute is less clear.

Comment: @rici: If it is, then someone misnamed the attribute. :P

Comment: Really, though, the prohibition on pure functions returning `void` wouldn't make sense in light of out parameters.

Comment: right. If out parameters are permitted, then `void` return should be permitted, too. And note that you could return a `struct`, which is normally implemented as a hidden out parameter.

Comment: Misnaming does happen. `static` :-)

Comment: @rici did you read the text? It does no such thing, op misread

Comment: @Antti rici got exactly what I meant.  But after the answers, I understand that there are cases where pure > idempotent which I ignored before

Comment: @antti: yes, I did. It says, in part, "functions declared with the pure attribute can safely read any non-volatile objects, and **modify the value of objects in a way that does not affect their return value or the observable state of the program.**" I interpret that to mean that `*a = *a` is acceptable unless `a` is a pointer to a volatile object. How is that different from what OP says?

Comment: @antti: it's a debatable point; as I said earlier, for me the intention is not clear. If the value of an object passed by reference was not set before the call, does setting it produce an "observable change"? How do you observe an initialization, given that you cannot have observed the indeterminate value of the uninitialized object? If you're correct about `pure` making it possible to remove *all* calls to a function, then pure functions cannot be used in the way proposed by OP. But the docs only talk about removing some of the repeated calls.

Comment: @antti: related, but different. Is this correct? `int getRandomNumber(void) __attribute__((pure)) { static int xkcd221 = 4; return xkcd221; }`

Comment: @rici Another example in the limits: `static int bar; int foo(void) __attribute__((pure)) {bar = 5; return bar;}` with the condition that no other function uses `bar`.

Comment: I believe both would be ok, @cacahuetefrito

Comment: @Antti: ok, thanks to the bug report, there's a good response (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91107#c1) which certainly supports your interpretation, showing that GCC does require a stronger guarantee than idempotence. (The example shows that GCC may optimise away a load of `dest[0]` if it knows that what that value was before the call.) I tend to agree with OP, though: that optimisation would be legit if the argument was `const`; you don't need purity for that. Purity does help with CSE by allowing memoisation of repeated calls.